# How to find a specific name from a string in sql server table data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I find a specific name from a string in the table data.

I want to find Katz only not katzav or DrKatz etc

I am using

```
SELECT * FROM NOTESTable WHERE NOTES LIKE '%Katz%'
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Within a string e.g. 
Today afternoon Katz saw a dozen patients -- OK
Dr Spencer saw patient Katzav today -- No

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If within a string, you want a single word:

```
SELECT * FROM NOTESTable WHERE NOTES LIKE '% Katz %'
```

Note: This does not work for the first or last word. If you want that you have to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM NOTESTable WHERE NOTES LIKE '% Katz %' OR  NOTES LIKE 'Katz %' OR NOTES LIKE '% Katz'
```

Comment: Using this method wouldn't `Katz`, without spaces, never come up?

Comment: Thats the point, they did not want it if it were not a whole word.

Comment: I actually hadn't seen the comment on the original question until after my comment here. I see how this applies now, good work!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried not using the % wild card?

```
SELECT * FROM NOTESTable WHERE NOTES = 'Katz'
```